# How to constrain argument by type member of type parameter in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types

The function reduceTo gets a type parameter indicating the kind of time series that should be returned, but the function splitInto requires a Period value. I want to make sure they are coherent so you can't do this:

```
reduceTo[MonthlySeries](period=Weekly)  // not ok
reduceTo[MonthlySeries](period=Monthly) // but this is ok
reduceTo[MonthlySeries]  // even better, derive the period from the type param
```

The type parameter should be sufficient but I can't seem to get the Period information I need from the parametrised type. Here's the simplified code:

```
sealed trait Period
case class Daily extends Period
case class Monthly extends Period


sealed abstract class TimeSeries {
    type T
}
case class DailySeries extends TimeSeries {
    type T = Daily.type
}
case class MonthlySeries extends TimeSeries {
    type T = Monthly.type
}

implicit class DailySeriesOps(lhs: DailySeries) {

    def reduceTo[G: TimeSeries](period: Period):G {
        // instead of sending the period in, how do I get
        // the period value from the type G?
        // Or at least constrain the period value?
        val s = splitInto(period, lhs)
        val reduced : G = ...
        // this is ugly
        assert(reduced.period == period, s"Reducing to $period but timeseries is ${reduced.period}")
    }
}
```

Initially I thought path dependent types would help so something like

```
def reduceTo[G: TimeSeries](period: G.T)
```

but that would require, from what I understand, that Daily would be a class defined inside DailySeries, which since it's used in other contexts is not ideal.

Another idea, which doesn't work, would be not to send the period parameter in but get the value from G, but since its instance doesn't exist yet, it doesn't work

```
def reduceTo... = {
  val period = G.T
  ...
}
```

[Update]

Also tried

```
def reduceTo[G : TimeSeries](period: TimeSeries#T: G = {
    val ts = reduce[F](period.asInstanceOf[GroupedPeriod], lhs)
```

But then this fails to compile with a type mismatch on reduceTo calls:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.example.metrics.Periods.Monthly.type
[error]  required: com.example.metrics.calculations.TimeSeries#T
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This would work: `def reduceTo[G <: TimeSeries](timeSeries: G)(period: timeSeries.T): G` Path dependent types are specific to the path of the current instance.

Comment: That would imply I would send in another time series just to constrain the period type, i.e. `reduceTo[MonthlySeries](MonthlySeries.empty, period=Monthly)` so not ideal, the repetition would be even greater..

Comment: More interesting part is how will you return anything from reduceTo? From what i know and looking on PECS, how will you create object of type G to return?

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk Good catch :) I simplified the code. The real signature has an implicit converter `def reduceTo[G <: GroupedSeries[F]](period: Period, op: (TimeSeries[F]) => TimeSeries[F])  (implicit converter: (Seq[DateTime], Seq[F]) => G): G = {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment if GroupedSeries has `type T` field you could use `period: G#T`, or if don't you would need to add additional generic parameter and use something like:

```
  def reduceTo[G <: GroupedSeries[_], T <: TimeSeries](period: T#T): G = {
    //Your code
  }
```

And with this my compiler is saying:

```
DailySeriesOps().reduceTo[DailySeries,DailySeries](Monthly) // I don't compile that
DailySeriesOps().reduceTo[DailySeries,DailySeries](Daily) // that i will
DailySeriesOps().reduceTo[MonthlySeries,MonthlySeries](Monthly) // that i will too
DailySeriesOps().reduceTo[MonthlySeries,MonthlySeries](Daily) // and not this one
```

But your question is not easy reproducible, so I don't know if this can answer your question, I hope it helps

Comment: Using `period: G#T` works :) Although had to use asInstanceOf to convert from G#T to Period type `val s = splitInto(period.asInstanceOf[Period], lhs)`. Even better would have been to be able to skip sending the period param in and just grabbing the period from the type G. This is better than what I had so thanks a lot :) But if you have any ideas on how we could skip the period param altogether, that would be great!

Comment: To skip period param and obtain type from just declared generic class, you could (I think) inside reduceTo declare: `type period = G#T`, and then use it from there :) Also if you need an instance, not type, it will be simpler, because you can just remove ".type" from types defined in TimeSeries classes :)

Comment: I need an instance. The problem is that I need it _before_ creating an instance of the type G#T. I need it when calling the splitInto function, before the converter which converts the result from splitInto into G#T. But thanks anyway :)